# Ansible: Fatal error thrown by include_tasks even if a block-rescue block is used

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook

I am trying to include multiple tasks based on some values defined in one hostvar but some fatal errors are thrown even if I'm using the block-rescue block. 
I have the variable ***profiles*** defined in ***host_vars/hostname.yml***:

```
profiles: '["profile1","trap1"]'
```

and the role ***test_profiles*** in ***/etc/ansible/roles***. Here, into the tasks directory I have the following .yml files: *profile1.yml, profile2.yml, main.yml*.

The content of main.yml file is:

```
- name: import profiles
   block:
     - include_tasks: "{{ item }}.yml"
       with_items: "{{ profiles|default([]) }}"
   rescue:
     - debug: msg='Error encountered while trying to include a .yml file corresponding to a defined profile from profiles variable. Profiles - "{{ profiles }}"'
   when: profiles is defined
```

Playbook's content is:

```
 - name: Test profiles config
   hosts: myhost
   roles:
     - test_profiles
```

The output is something like this:

```
TASK [test_profiles : include_tasks] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
included: /etc/ansible/roles/test_profiles/tasks/profile.yml for <my_host>
fatal: [<my_host>]: FAILED! => {"reason": "Unable to retrieve file contents\nCould not find or access '/etc/ansible/trap1.yml'"}

TASK [test_profiles : Ensure that profile directory exists into the D:\profiles directory] ************************************************************************************************
ok: [<my_host>]

TASK [test_profiles : Update profile.properties file] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [<my_host>]

TASK [test_profiles : debug] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [<my_host>] => {
    "msg": "Error encountered while trying to include a .yml file corresponding to a defined profile from profiles variable. Profiles - \"[\"profile1\",\"trap1\"]\""
}
        to retry, use: --limit @/etc/ansible/playbook_test_profiles.retry

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
<my_host>                 : ok=5    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

From my point of view that fatal error should not appear. What am I doing wrong here and how can I get rid of this? I've also tried with a **when** conditional but without success.

I'm using **Ansible 2.4.2.0** and the tasks are performed for some windows hosts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I removed the block-rescue block. I've found out a way to check if my .yml file exists. This is using the ***role_path*** variable (which will return the current role’s path - available since Ansible 1.8 - this works only inside a role) and the test ***is_file***.

My main.yml for the above described role is looking like this:

```
- name: Import profiles
   include_tasks: "{{ item }}.yml"
   with_items: "{{ profiles|default([]) }}"
   when: (role_path + '/tasks/' + item + '.yml') | is_file
```

Because of this check a fatal exception will no longer be thrown - the trap1.yml file will be skipped.

The output will be something like:

```
TASK [test_profiles : Import profiles] ***********************************************************
skipping: [<my_host>] => (item=trap1)
included: /etc/ansible/roles/test_profiles/tasks/profile1.yml for <my_host>

TASK [test_profiles : Ensure that profile directory exists into the D:\profiles directory] *******
ok: [<my_host>]

TASK [test_profiles : Update profile.properties file] ********************************************
changed: [<my_host>]
        to retry, use: --limit @/etc/ansible/playbook_test_profiles.retry

PLAY RECAP ***************************************************************************************
<my_host>                 : ok=4    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

I'm OK with this solution but I'm open to some other suggestions too.

Answer (score 1):

`block`/`rescue` does not prevent error from happening. It detects failed task and execute `rescue` block to recover from the error. But the failed task is still there and will be visible in play recap.

I'd recommend to use fail fast approach when designing playbooks. In your case you can scan your local files to test if user input (supplied configuration) is valid: whether profiles files are in place. User `assert`/`fail` modules.